# UNC space in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I've seen lots of posts on here (and elsewhere) with a solution to the problem of finding the available free space on a UNC path, but these all involve using GetDiskFreeSpaceEx which only appears to be available in C.

I've included it in some test code and get:

```
Error   BC30451 'GetDiskFreeSpaceEx' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

The IDE offers the solutions of creating a method or a property.

Trying this in a console program...

What is the VB equivalent of this?

Comment: It is available to VB code but it's a Windows API function so you have to use Platform Invoke (pinvoke) to execute it. You should investigate how to do that. There will be lots of examples around, most commonly of the `SendMessage` API, possibly in combination with `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx`. Just be sure that, if you follow any VB examples, they are written for VB.NET or you make the appropriate changes from the VB6 equivalent, which mainly means replacing `Long` with `Integer`.

Comment: You have to [pinvoke it](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/getdiskfreespace.html?diff=y).  Quite a mess, but gets you going.

Comment: All the code on that page refers to C and C#. At the risk of sounding a complete twonk, even when I try to code convert it, the results don't work.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney. I've been trying to read around the subject but this is all alien to me! I'll try more research on the pinvoke in VB.Net

Comment: The VB.Net function call signature is `<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> Friend Shared Function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(lpDirectoryName As String, ByRef lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller As ULong, ByRef lpTotalNumberOfBytes As ULong, ByRef lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes As ULong) As Boolean End Function` (in 3 lines)

Comment: Call it as: `Dim result = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(sharePath, freeBytesForCaller, totalbytes, totalFreeBytes)`, where `sharePath` must be written as `"\\ComputerName\Share\"`. Of course, also declare the other 3 `ULong` variables beforehand. If `result = True`, the function call was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with P/Invoke, I usually write a *class* with the name of the method and not only the method declaration itself and *try* to expose the functionality in a .NET fashion instead of low-level C++ style.

e.g. in the method description of the native `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` function it is mentioned that in case the provided path is an UNC-path the trailing backslash is mandatory!

- C++ style: Write it in the description, if the caller does not provide it in that fashion, they are to blame themselves, RTFM.
- .NET style: We adjust it for the caller, they do not have to worry about such implementation details.

I would also provide 3 different methods for each available information (I included a 4th one for the space used), and a common one to get more than one value at once.

Here how it could look:

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace PInvoke.Kernel32

    Public Class GetDiskFreeSpaceEx

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Retrieves the number of bytes currently available to the caller. This takes into account any quotas etc. that may
        ''' exist on the folder resp. file share.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="folderName">The name of the path to retrieve the for me available bytes from.</param>
        ''' <returns>The maximum number of bytes that are currently available for me to use.</returns>
        Public Shared Function GetAvailableBytesToCaller(folderName As String) As UInt64
            Dim result As SizeInfo = Invoke(folderName)
            Return result.BytesAvailableToCaller
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Retrieves the number of bytes currently available on the according volume. This may be more than I can use,
        ''' see <see cref="GetAvailableBytesToCaller(String)" /> for a method that respects quotas etc.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="folderName">The name of the path to retrieve the (in general) available bytes from.</param>
        ''' <returns>The maximum number of bytes that are available for all users together.</returns>
        Public Shared Function GetAvailableBytesInTotal(folderName As String) As UInt64
            Dim result As SizeInfo = Invoke(folderName)
            Return result.BytesAvailableInTotal
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Retrieves the number of bytes currently used on the according volume. This value corresponds to 
        ''' <see cref="GetBytesInTotal(String)"/> - <see cref="GetAvailableBytesInTotal(String)"/>.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="folderName">The name of the path to retrieve the used bytes from.</param>
        ''' <returns>The number of bytes that are already used by all users together.</returns>
        Public Shared Function GetUsedBytesInTotal(folderName As String) As UInt64
            Dim result As SizeInfo = Invoke(folderName)
            Return result.BytesUsedInTotal
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Retrieves the size in bytes of the according volume (the total of already used and available space).
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="folderName">The name of the path to retrieve the (in general) available bytes from.</param>
        ''' <returns>The maximum number of bytes that are available for all users together.</returns>
        Public Shared Function GetBytesInTotal(folderName As String) As UInt64
            Dim result As SizeInfo = Invoke(folderName)
            Return result.TotalNumberOfBytes
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Retrieves a <see cref="SizeInfo"/> object containing the information about how many bytes are available at
        ''' the given path in general or for the current user account, how much is the total and how much is already
        ''' used.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="folderName">The name of the path from which to retrieve the size info.</param>
        ''' <returns>The according size info object.</returns>
        Public Shared Function Invoke(folderName As String) As SizeInfo
            'Check argument
            If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderName)) Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(folderName), "The folder's name must not be null, empty or white-space!")
            End If
            'Expand environment variables
            Try
                folderName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(folderName)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New ArgumentException($"Unable to expand possible environment variables of folder '{folderName}'! See inner exception for details...", ex)
            End Try
            'Get full path
            Try
                folderName = Path.GetFullPath(folderName)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New ArgumentException($"Unable to retrieve absolute path of folder '{folderName}'! See inner exception for details...", ex)
            End Try
            'Append final back-slash (which is mandatory for UNC paths)
            folderName = folderName.Replace(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
            If (Not folderName.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)) Then
                folderName &= Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
            End If
            'Invoke method
            Dim bytesAvailableToCaller As UInt64
            Dim bytesInTotal As UInt64
            Dim bytesAvailableInGeneral As UInt64
            Dim success As Boolean = Invoke(folderName, bytesAvailableToCaller, bytesInTotal, bytesAvailableInGeneral)
            If (Not success) Then Throw New Win32Exception()
            'Return result
            Return New SizeInfo(bytesAvailableToCaller, bytesInTotal, bytesAvailableInGeneral)
        End Function

        'Private Methods

        <DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetDiskFreeSpaceExW", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
        Private Shared Function Invoke(folderName As String, ByRef bytesAvailableToCaller As UInt64, ByRef bytesInTotal As UInt64, ByRef bytesAvailableInGeneral As UInt64) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
        End Function


        '************************************************************************************************************************
        ' Inner Class "SizeInfo"
        '************************************************************************************************************************

        Public Class SizeInfo

            Public Sub New(freeBytesAvailableToCaller As UInt64, totalNumberOfBytes As UInt64, freeBytesAvailableInTotal As UInt64)
                Me.BytesAvailableToCaller = freeBytesAvailableToCaller
                Me.BytesAvailableInTotal = freeBytesAvailableInTotal
                Me.TotalNumberOfBytes = totalNumberOfBytes
            End Sub

            Public ReadOnly Property BytesAvailableToCaller As UInt64

            Public ReadOnly Property BytesAvailableInTotal As UInt64

            Public ReadOnly Property BytesUsedInTotal As UInt64
                Get
                    Dim total As UInt64 = TotalNumberOfBytes
                    Dim available As UInt64 = BytesAvailableInTotal
                    If (total <= available) Then Return 0
                    Return total - available
                End Get
            End Property

            Public ReadOnly Property TotalNumberOfBytes As UInt64

        End Class

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: Many thanks Christoph. This seems to have done what I need. Much appreciated.